# Multiple Unity Scene Script for iOS Build

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Two Scenes in Unity. Have to write a script for controlling unity scenes(2) in native iOS app, suppose 2 buttons in a native app when I click 1st button have to show scene1 and the 2nd button for scene2 like so. I found a script for android but need to write it for iOS.
Attached Script for Android,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.VR;
using System;

public class AnimatorScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Animator animation;
    AndroidJavaObject intent , currentActivity , extras;
    bool hasExtra;
    string arguments;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        try
        {

        AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
        hasExtra = intent.Call<bool> ("hasExtra", "test_val");
         Debug.Log(hasExtra);
        Debug.Log("start");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
        }

    }

    public void loadScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

        if (hasExtra) 
        {
            Debug.Log("has extra");
            extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getExtras");
            arguments = extras.Call<string> ("getString", "test_val");
            if(string.Equals(arguments,"scene1"))
             {
                 animation.Play("dancing_warrior_sun-001");
             }
             if(string.Equals(arguments,"scene2"))
             {
                //  animation.Play("seating_poses-001");
                 SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
             }
             else Debug.Log("No Animation Found");

            Debug.Log(arguments);
        } 
        else 
        {

            Debug.Log("no extra");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of Scene change/switch you can do,

1) In Unity place button by UI, and write script for scene change as follows,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuActions : MonoBehaviour {
  public void MENU_ACTION_NextButton(string sceneName)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(sceneName);
    }
}
```

Drag this script to Main camera and click button, at the bottom of inspector click to add this main camera and name your scene name that have to be changed.Do this for scene 2 with same script and name the scene as well.
[image]

2) If you have button in your native app then write scripts as follows and try to write script for void update as well,

```
   using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour {

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            //SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
// try your script................
        }


    public void ChangeScene( string scene ) {
       // Application.LoadLevel(scene);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
    }
    }
```

Hope this will give you the concept..

Answer (score 0):

[Building an application with a native plugin for iOS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

You can follow the official document, use **UnitySendMessage** from iOS to call the scene-control script at Unity.

Comment: I am beginner in unity not familiar with c#. I wish to get full script support for 2 Scenes.

Comment: I found an article implement what you want. https://the-nerd.be/2014/08/07/call-methods-on-unity3d-straight-from-your-objective-c-code/